# Proposal to revise / rewrite Java community wiki Q&A for common compiler messages

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) receives every day a good amount of questions regarding common compiler errors, exceptions and warnings. These questions are usually closed as duplicates of some old question dealing with the same compiler message. The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) lists a few of those under "Debugging" and I have added a few more to the list below:

- [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/)
- [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)
- [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)
- [Java Package, Project , NoSuchMethod error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647154/java-package-project-nosuchmethod-error)
- [Java compile error: cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237209/java-compile-error-cannot-find-symbol), though we have [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)
- [Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372595/class-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-classt-should-be-parameterized)
- [What does it mean: The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514881/understanding-this-warning-the-serializable-class-does-not-declare-a-static-fin) and [Understanding this warning: The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288937/what-does-it-mean-the-serializable-class-does-not-declare-a-static-final-serial)
- [No Such Element Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032099/no-such-element-exception)

I'm not saying that the current situation is bad, but

- the questions are not good questions by today's standards and some of the answers too. Looking at [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/), the question received over 200 upvotes for what would today be 10 downvotes and a 2-min closure. [NCDFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) is similar.
- the questions were written by new "programmers" who hardly had any idea what is happening and as such wrote uninformative and somewhat uneducated questions.
- new solutions come up with new Java versions and adding another answer to those which were upvoted 5 years ago will hardly be seen. As an example, in Java 8 the [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) was added and is relevant for the null pointer questions.

Due to the high popularity of these types of questions, I would like to *propose a rewrite of questions (and answers) dealing with common compiler messages* with the following benefits. The questions and answers will...

- be written by users who have a clue about and *foresight* into what the problem is. Knowing the general and common cases when these messages pop up and why is crucial for formulating a good question.
- fit each other well as they were planned ahead-of-time (and not just-in-time) to do so. It's always easier to write answers for questions that structure themselves well in first place and show the stack trace and line number.
- be written pedagogically and not in the "solve my current problem and that's it" fashion which is so common.
- be standardized in their structure and content. They will include explanations, links to API (JLS if viable) and possibly to the current used-for-duplicate questions, code and input & output examples and be titled similarly.

Then we can update the tag wiki with them and start closing as duplicates pointing to these questions with the *hope that they will be more helpful* to the asker who just had their question closed.

The [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) is great, but the question could be improved. It's just an example, but we can learn from it.

I'm bringing this up for discussion for two main reasons:

1. I don't want to do it and have "the community" chop my head off for trying to improve the wheel.
2. This will be best done as a community effort with improvements coming from experienced users.

If you have any more links to this type of question, comment and I'll edit them in. Any thoughts, proposals, volunteers?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a gold badge holder in Java, and as a Java developer/tutor, I'm not convinced that we need a *rewrite* of these questions or answers.

First of all, the NPE and NCDFE were both questions that were written **back in 2008**.  Yes, they'd be closed *now*, but in all honesty, these were good and acceptable questions back then, back when Stack Overflow was trying to figure things out.

(It may have even been the case that, as the site grew and matured, that the standards changed *because* these questions were already asked prior.)

Your second point...

> the questions were written by new "programmers" who hardly had any idea what is happening and as such wrote uninformative and somewhat uneducated questions.

...is irrelevant *at best* and inflammatory at worst.

Do you *honestly* expect everyone to just *know* all of the things about a language they're working with?  What would the point of Stack Overflow then, if not for a place to ask these questions?  Again, I maintain that these questions would have likely been closed if they were asked now, but I suspect that the only reason that they'd have been closed now is that someone *else* would have supplied a canonical question to fill the void left by them.

Your third point may have some merit, but in the case of NPEs and `Optional`, [there's already a separate question about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681243/should-i-use-java8-guava-optional-for-every-method-that-may-return-null)  [Lots of them, actually.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type)  Almost to the point that I would personally downvote an answer that said `Optional` solves the whole NPE problem when it really wasn't meant to.

Besides that, you don't describe anything about:

- What those sorts of questions would *look* like in this day and age, providing us talking points about why we would and wouldn't like to see the question phrased in a specific way
- How this will actually benefit the site, since by and large, everyone looking for `NullPointerException` has already seen the stack trace
- Why it's necessary, since those questions get a lot of mileage and are definitely chock full of knowledge

So no, I'm not convinced we need a rewrite.